# Fetcher in Currency Converter Ubuntu app

Tags: application-development

I saw in the Ubuntu phone app tutorial that the fetcher in the currency converter is from ecb's web page. Do you know if that data can be legally used in a real app or web page? I suspect that data from other pages such as Yahoo finance (they also have a currency converter among other things such as stock data) can't be used because Yahoo! has stated on their web page that "By accessing the Yahoo! site, you agree not to redistribute the information found therein.". I'm sure that the Ubuntu Mobile OS will be a great mobile os!

Answer (score 1):

The use of the data is documented on the ecb stats page. From http://www.ecb.int/stats/html/escbstats.en.html:

> **Policy regarding the reuse of ESCB statistics**
>
> The European System of Central Banks (ESCB) releases its statistics
> and related methodologies via the websites of the European Central
> Bank (ECB) and the national central banks (NCBs), and the ESCB makes
> continuous efforts to facilitate their use. Against this background,
> the ESCB would like to set out its common policy regarding the reuse
> of ESCB statistics.
>
> Policy regarding the reuse of ESCB statistics
>
> - The ESCB is committed to
>   providing its statistics free of charge as a public good of high
>   quality irrespective of any subsequent commercial or non-commercial
>   use.
> - The ESCB subscribes to a policy of free access and free reuse
>   regarding its publicly released statistics, subject to the conditions
>   described below.
> - The ESCB attaches great importance to the quality of
>   its statistics, in accordance with the principles set out in the
>   [Public commitment on European Statistics by the ESCB.](http://www.ecb.int/stats/html/pcstats.en.html)
>
> Common conditions for the reuse of ESCB statistics
>
> All publicly available ESCB statistics may be reused free of charge on
> the condition that the source is quoted (e.g. “Source: ECB
> statistics.”) and that the statistics (including metadata) are not
> modified. The policy of free access and free reuse does not imply a
> right to obtain confidential data.
>
> The following additional rules apply:
>
> 1. The right of free reuse refers
>    to statistics as made available to the public in standard format,
>    which must be used in accordance with the respective disclaimers
>    issued by the ECB and the NCBs. [Disclaimer & copyright](http://www.ecb.int/home/html/disclaimer.en.html)
> 2. The right of
>    free reuse does not apply to third-party data without a prior
>    permission from the originator.
> 3. Users are not entitled to expect
>    continuity of all ESCB statistics published and should note that
>    statistics may be changed as a result of revisions or other updates.
> 4. Access to ESCB statistics may be restricted in exceptional
>    circumstances, for example if a user is acting in a manner contrary to
>    the interests of other users.